# Update-database -script no EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, migrations

No EF6 eu podia executar o comando "update-database -script" do Migrations para ver o script que seria executo no banco. Como consigo isso no EF Core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize `script-migration` depois de rodar o `Add-Migration`, dessa forma ele irá gerar o arquivo **SQL** pra você.

Você também pode usar o parâmetro `Verbose` junto ao `update-database` para ver o script que foi executado no console:

```
update-database -Verbose
```